# Toggle group of markers on googlemaps APi v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have one heatmap with some markers. I can toggle all markers at the same time and I'm trying to toggle them category-by-category (like on this example: http://jsfiddle.net/huMtu/361/).

I've tried to divide the locations var in 1 and 2 (same with the var markers), but I'm a beginner and cannot tell why it's not working.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">    

    <title>Agenda</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=visualization"></script>
    <script>    



var map, pointarray, heatmap;

var taxiData = [

new google.maps.LatLng(-23.574917, -46.392787),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.580376, -46.389232),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.402486, -46.750809),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.403860, -46.752856),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.404044, -46.761739),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.410588, -46.760297),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.426872, -46.724692),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.438656, -46.802163),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.439153, -46.708424),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.444647, -46.553665),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.445394, -46.731450),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.447098, -46.589690),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.447697, -46.799269),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.447982, -46.734821),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.450721, -46.573869),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.455090, -46.716561),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.457128, -46.583936),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.458946, -46.604814),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.460150, -46.582184),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.460162, -46.579276),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.461555, -46.709902),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.473637, -46.684330),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.473637, -46.684330),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.475226, -46.581618),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.475864, -46.697348),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.476219, -46.664631),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.478657, -46.420357),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.478879, -46.384664),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.479145, -46.415483),
new google.maps.LatLng(-23.479875, -46.381180),


];





function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.5934217, -46.6627102),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);
  heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({data: pointArray});




  heatmap.setMap(map);





  var locations = [
['GREEN, 07/08/2014',-23.513202, -46.390331,'green-dot.png'],

    ];

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var iconBase = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';
    var marker, i;
    window.markers = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: iconBase + locations[i][3]
      });
      markers.push(marker);
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

    function AutoCenter() {
      //  Create a new viewpoint bound
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      //  Go through each...
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      bounds.extend(markers[i].position)
      }
      //  Fit these bounds to the map
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    AutoCenter();

}


  var locations2 = [
['BLUE, 04/12/2014',-23.514345, -46.530521,'blue-dot.png'],
['RED, 21/05/2013',-23.514924, -46.538907,'red-dot.png'],
['YELLOW, 25/03/2015',-23.531998, -46.711497,'yellow-dot.png'],

    ];

    var infowindow2 = new google.maps.Infowindow2();
    var iconBase = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';
    var marker2, i;
    window.markers2 = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < locations2.length; i++) {  
      marker2 = new google.maps.Marker2({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations2[i][1], locations2[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: iconBase + locations2[i][3]
      });
      markers2.push(marker2);
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', (function(marker2, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow2.setContent(locations2[i][0]);
          infowindow2.open(map, marker2);
        }
      })(marker2, i));
    }



function toggleMarkers() {
    if (markers[0].getMap() != null) {var arg = null;} else {var arg = map;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {markers[i].setMap(arg);}
}

function toggleMarkers2() {
    if (markers2[0].getMap() != null) {var arg = null;} else {var arg = map;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < markers2.length; i++) {markers2[i].setMap(arg);}
}

function toggleHeatmap() {

    if (heatmap.getMap() != null) {
        heatmap.setMap(null);
    } else {
        heatmap.setMap(map);
    }
}


function changeGradient() {
  var gradient = [
    'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
    'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
    'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
    'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
    'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)']

heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);}

function changeRadius() {
  heatmap.set('radius', heatmap.get('radius') ? null : 20);}

function changeOpacity() {
  heatmap.set('opacity', heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.2);}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <button onclick="toggleMarkers()">Toggle Markers</button>
      <button onclick="toggleMarkers2()">Toggle Markers2</button>
      <button onclick="toggleHeatmap()">Toggle Heatmap</button>
      <button onclick="changeGradient()">Change Color</button>
      <button onclick="changeRadius()">Change radius</button>
      <button onclick="changeOpacity()">Change pacity</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Could you help me find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Uncaught ReferenceError: markers is not defined`
2. `Uncaught ReferenceError: markers2 is not defined`
3. `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on

   - `var infowindow2 = new google.maps.Infowindow2();` (there is on google.maps.Infowindow2 object)
   - `marker2 = new google.maps.Marker2` (there is no google.maps.Marker2 object).

Fix those and [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/r2d5gmcL/)

code snippet:

```js
var map, pointarray, heatmap;
var markers = [];
var markers2 = [];

var taxiData = [

  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.574917, -46.392787),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.580376, -46.389232),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.402486, -46.750809),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.403860, -46.752856),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.404044, -46.761739),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.410588, -46.760297),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.426872, -46.724692),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.438656, -46.802163),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.439153, -46.708424),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.444647, -46.553665),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.445394, -46.731450),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.447098, -46.589690),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.447697, -46.799269),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.447982, -46.734821),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.450721, -46.573869),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.455090, -46.716561),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.457128, -46.583936),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.458946, -46.604814),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.460150, -46.582184),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.460162, -46.579276),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.461555, -46.709902),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.473637, -46.684330),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.473637, -46.684330),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.475226, -46.581618),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.475864, -46.697348),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.476219, -46.664631),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.478657, -46.420357),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.478879, -46.384664),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.479145, -46.415483),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-23.479875, -46.381180),


];





function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.5934217, -46.6627102),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);
  heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: pointArray
  });




  heatmap.setMap(map);





  var locations = [
    ['GREEN, 07/08/2014', -23.513202, -46.390331, 'green-dot.png']

  ];

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var iconBase = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';
  var marker, i;
  window.markers = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      icon: iconBase + locations[i][3]
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    })(marker, i));
  }

  function AutoCenter() {
    //  Create a new viewpoint bound
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    //  Go through each...
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      bounds.extend(markers[i].position)
    };
    //  Fit these bounds to the map
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
  AutoCenter();

}


var locations2 = [
  ['BLUE, 04/12/2014', -23.514345, -46.530521, 'blue-dot.png'],
  ['RED, 21/05/2013', -23.514924, -46.538907, 'red-dot.png'],
  ['YELLOW, 25/03/2015', -23.531998, -46.711497, 'yellow-dot.png']

];

var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var iconBase = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';
var marker2, i;
window.markers2 = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < locations2.length; i++) {
  marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations2[i][1], locations2[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: iconBase + locations2[i][3]
  });
  markers2.push(marker2);
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', (function(marker2, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow2.setContent(locations2[i][0]);
      infowindow2.open(map, marker2);
    };
  })(marker2, i));
}



function toggleMarkers() {
  if (markers[0].getMap() != null) {
    var arg = null;
  } else {
    var arg = map;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(arg);
  }
}

function toggleMarkers2() {
  if (markers2[0].getMap() != null) {
    var arg = null;
  } else {
    var arg = map;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < markers2.length; i++) {
    markers2[i].setMap(arg);
  }
}

function toggleHeatmap() {

  if (heatmap.getMap() != null) {
    heatmap.setMap(null);
  } else {
    heatmap.setMap(map);
  }
}


function changeGradient() {
  var gradient = [
    'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
    'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
    'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
    'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
    'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
  ];

  heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
}

function changeRadius() {
  heatmap.set('radius', heatmap.get('radius') ? null : 20);
}

function changeOpacity() {
  heatmap.set('opacity', heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.2);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization"></script>
<div id="panel">
  <button onclick="toggleMarkers()">Toggle Markers</button>
  <button onclick="toggleMarkers2()">Toggle Markers2</button>
  <button onclick="toggleHeatmap()">Toggle Heatmap</button>
  <button onclick="changeGradient()">Change Color</button>
  <button onclick="changeRadius()">Change Radius</button>
  <button onclick="changeOpacity()">Change Opacity</button>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```